# Triggers in PeopleSoft

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

Can we create triggers in PeopleSoft when running Peoplesoft App Engine?

We want to create triggers for some tables based on the selection at the time of App Engine

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the %Execute function to execute multiple sql statements or an pl/sql block from an AE program. This way you could create a trigger in an AE Program.

Documentation can be found in the Oracle PeopleBooks here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55243_01/pt854pbr0/eng/pt/tape/langref_UsingApplicationEngineMeta-SQL-0771d9.html#topofpage

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that.
you can create a trigger on insert on PSPRCSRQST table, you will have process name in prcsname field, capture and do what ever you want